# Packet IP identification generation

Tags: networking, operating-system, ip, packet, tcp

I am looking into IP Packet structure and I was wondering how the Operating Systems do generate IP identification numbers. I am sure that different platforms will have different algorithms.

I will be thankful if anyone can point out to some solid references to understand the details.
Thanks

Comment: can you be more specific on what you mean? when you say "IP identification numbers", which field in the IP header you refer to?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to know how operating systems implement things, just look at the source code for one of the several available free operating systems. In this case, the code you're looking for is in Linux's [__ip_select_ident](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/route.c#L491) function.

It looks like it keeps some state information (basically a counter) that is per-peer (per-destination-address), but it also has a fallback algorithm in case looking up this state information fails.

Comment: Any books/articles you would recommend? Im no expert in C programming. It will be difficult to dive in the OS source code. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would believe that choosing a random number for the IP Frag Id lessens the vulnerability to spoofing attacks.  But I suppose it's not that simple

A couple references:
[unique identification requirement](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc791.txt), [high data rate issue](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4963), and [vulnerability issues](http://static.usenix.org/event/woot/tech/final_files/Gilad.pdf)

Comment: Thanks, i will go through the above